# use pointer pass value

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning C and pointers. I am following the code below and have a couple of questions.

1. My MS Visual Studio complains: uninitialized local variable 'day_ret' used. I then complied using Geany (another IDE) and it works. Is there something wrong with this code?
2. I feel the author who wrote the code should put some values to month and day. Otherwise, it will just print out the memory address, right? I want to know if I should put the initial value just after mian?

Reference:
www.publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/pointers.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void date(int *, int *);     /* declare the function */

int main(){
      int month, day;
      date (&day, &month);
      printf("day is %d, month is %d\n", day, month);
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void date(int *day_p, int *month_p){
      int day_ret, month_ret;
      /*
       * At this point, calculate the day and month
       * values in day_ret and month_ret respectively.
       */
      *day_p = day_ret;
      *month_p = month_ret;
}
```

Comment: In short, day_ret contains _garbage_ value, and eventually, `day_p` points to a location containing garbage.

Comment: You should follow the directions given in the comments. You need to fill in values for `day_ret` and `month_ret` before returning them. Otherwise, everything is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes - you're missing the code in the comments:

   ```
   /*
    * At this point, calculate the day and month
    * values in day_ret and month_ret respectively.
    */
   ```

   That code would set `day_ret` and `month_ret`. Without the missing code, it's effectively incomplete, and you could get *any* value for `day` and `month`.
2. No, it's not going to print out pointers. `month` and `day` are integer variables. Pointers to those variables are being passed to the `date` method, which is storing values via those pointers. The values are then being printed.